# How to make two columns in a TableRow, same “width” using the biggest one

Tags: java, android

I have a simple TableRow layout with two TextView columns each:

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>
```

In “onCreate”, programmatically set the text on each columns:

```
TextView col1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView col2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
col1.setText("LARGE TEXT COLUMN");
col2.setText("SHORT");
```

The following code works like a charm to set the col2 width programmatically, for any size I like:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = col2.getLayoutParams();
params.width = XXX;
col2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The idea is to read “col1” width, to assign it to “col2”, but, no matter where I put tha following code in “onCreate” or “onResume”, “col1.getWidth()” or “col1. getMeasuredWidth()”  is always cero “0”:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = col2.getLayoutParams();
params.width = col1.getWidth();
col2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

.. or

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = col2.getLayoutParams();
params.width = col1.getMeasuredWidth();
col2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to use weightsum for tablerow and then weight=1 for each textview?

Comment: R.F.> This was only a example. The real application have more than 2 columns with different sizes, but only column 2 haves to be the same size has column 1, so, applying weight it’s not an option in my case. The example is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

A none elegant solution is to add a dummy invisible table row with the col2 = col1 content, so it will have the same side, but again, its not elegant.

```
<TableRow
    android:visibility="invisible">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv1_dummy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv2_dummy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp">
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>
```

and then ...

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_dummy)).setText("LARGE TEXT COLUMN");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2_dummy)).setText("LARGE TEXT COLUMN");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText("LARGE TEXT COLUMN");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText("SHORT");
```

or the real dummy none elegant xml code without any programmatically code:

BEFORE:

```
        <TableRow android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/m_avaItems"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/w_tokens"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
            <TextView
                android:text= "@string/w_usd"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
        </TableRow>
```

[image]

AFTER:

```
        <TableRow
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="center">
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_span="2"/>
            <TextView
                android:text= "@string/w_tokens"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/m_avaItems"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/w_tokens"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
            <TextView
                android:text= "@string/w_usd"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                style="@style/Text_Shop" />
        </TableRow>
```

[image]

If some one send me a simple nice programmatically code rater thant that none elegant dummy XML code, have a big elegant hug from me. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Wrap <`TableRow`> within <`TableLayout`>

```
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                   <TextView...>

            </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```